# How do I integrate Data-Flow with Spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud

I have a batch application that works as db to db, but it only works on my "local" computer.

I want to integrate it with spring cloud data-flow to view and manage it via data-flow.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

**Can I install data-flow manually, has anyone done this before?
and the data-flow interface is running on localhost. But now how do I communicate my batch project on my "local" computer with the data-flow on "localhost"?**

Comment: Are you using spring-batch within a standalone spring boot application?  If so, you might be able to use https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin

Comment: Hi! Yes I have a standalone spring batch application and I want to integrate it with spring data-flow. But I have to use data-flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can run SCDF locally, see https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/manual/.

Then, you can register your Spring Batch app in SCDF as described here: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/batch/spring-batch/. You might need to make it a Spring Boot/ Cloud Task app though.